# SQL nested request

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tabled:

1. `transaction` - general info about user balance change. `primary key : transaction_id`.
2. `bet_transactions` - special info about bet, `foreign key : transaction_id`.
3. `win_transaction` - same as `bet_transactions`, but contain `wins`.

I want to get **sum of all bets and wins**.
I came up with this:

```
select
    u.username as username,
    u.balance as balance,
    sum(bt.amount) as bet_sum,
    sum(wt.amount) as win_sum
from
    users u,
    (
        select 
            t.*
        from 
            transactions t,
            bet_transactions b
        where 
            t.transaction_id = b.transaction_id
    ) bt,
    (
        select 
            t.*
        from 
            transactions t,
            win_transactions w
        where 
            t.transaction_id = w.transaction_id
    ) wt
where
    u.username = bt.username and
    u.username = wt.username
group by
    u.username
```

It doesn't work properly: I always get only one row and sums are not correct.
But if I remove one of nested parts like this, it starts to work as expected. What am I doing wrong?

```
select
    u.username as username,
    u.balance as balance,
    sum(bt.amount) as bet_sum
from
    users u,
    (
        select 
            t.*
        from 
            transactions t,
            bet_transactions b
        where 
            t.transaction_id = b.transaction_id
    ) bt
where
    u.username = bt.username
group by
    u.username
```

Comment: This is a join syntax we used in the 1980s. It was made redundant in 1992. You shouldn't use it anymore. Use proper ANSI joins instead which are less prone to errors and easier to read and maintain (`from transactions t join bet_transactions b on t.transaction_id = b.transaction_id`).

Comment: The amount (bet or win) is in the table `transaction`? That means that you only look up `bet_transactions` and `win_transactions` in order to find out whether a transaction is bet or win or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move aggregate functions and group by to nested sub-queries, something like this:

```
select
    u.username as username,
    u.balance as balance,
    bt.bet_sum,
    wt.win_sum
from
    users u
    left outer join 
    (
        select 
            t.username, sum(b.amount) as bet_sum
        from 
            transactions t,
            bet_transactions b
        where 
            t.transaction_id = b.transaction_id
        group by
            t.username
    ) bt
       on u.username = bt.username
    left outer join
    (
        select 
            t.username, sum(w.amount) as win_sum
        from 
            transactions t,
            win_transactions w
        where 
            t.transaction_id = w.transaction_id
        group by
            t.username
    ) wt
        on u.username = wt.username
```

More readable with CTE:

```
WITH 
bt as 
     (
        select 
            t.username, sum(b.amount) as bet_sum
        from 
            transactions t,
            bet_transactions b
        where 
            t.transaction_id = b.transaction_id
        group by
            t.username
    ),
wt as
    (
        select 
            t.username, sum(w.amount) as win_sum
        from 
            transactions t,
            win_transactions w
        where 
            t.transaction_id = w.transaction_id
        group by
            t.username
    ) 
select
    u.username as username,
    u.balance as balance,
    bt.bet_sum,
    wt.win_sum
from
    users u
    left outer join bt
       on u.username = bt.username
    left outer join wt
        on u.username = wt.username
```

**EDITED**:

I switched to proper ANSI join syntax, also to outer joins and CTE. Thanks [@ThorstenKettner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270762/thorsten-kettner) about suggestion.

Comment: Remove `group by u.username` and then simply select `u.username, u.balance, ...`, as this is a pseudo aggregation doing nothing. Qualify `bet_sum` with `bt.bet_sum` and `win_sum` with `wt.win_sum` for readability. And switch to proper ANSI joins for the same reason..

Comment: Hi @ThorstenKettner, is done. Thanks you about suggestion.